# Add a user to the administrator group remotely

Tags: adfs

Can a sysadmin add a user as a local administrator remotely by using ADFS?
I would like to avoid to do it from every machine.

/Marco

Answer (score 0):

No - ADFS is used for authentication, not for provisioning.

There is no ADUC-like functionality.

You could probably customize it (depending on the version you are using) but (security wise) that's probably not a good idea.